# source code for linux shell utility pidof

Tags: linux, shell

Experts,

How do I see the source code for the Linux shell command pidof ? Based on the answers for related questions I checked in the GNU coreutils. It isn't there..

Comment: Google for `pidof.c`, there are plenty of results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on Debian system like Ubuntu you can try something on these lines:
`dpkg -S <utility>`, this will tell you which package installed this utility; then you can get the source using `apt-get source <package-name>`. To get the source make sure you have `deb-src` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
For example on Ubuntu system I use:

```
$ dpkg -S pidof
sysvinit-utils: /bin/pidof
sysvinit-utils: /usr/share/man/man8/pidof.8.gz
```

So the package name is sysvinit-utils

```
$ apt-get source sysvinit-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'sysvinit' as source package instead of 'sysvinit-utils'
NOTICE: 'sysvinit' packaging is maintained in the 'Svn' version control system at:
svn://svn.debian.org/pkg-sysvinit/sysvinit/trunk
...
dpkg-source: info: extracting sysvinit in sysvinit-2.87dsf
dpkg-source: info: unpacking sysvinit_2.87dsf-4ubuntu17.4.tar.gz
```

Source package picked. It also inform about svn where the source is maintained.

```
$ ls sysvinit*
sysvinit_2.87dsf-4ubuntu17.4.dsc  sysvinit_2.87dsf-4ubuntu17.4.tar.gz

sysvinit-2.87dsf:
contrib/  COPYRIGHT  debian/  doc/  man/  obsolete/  README  src/
```

I am sure there should be equivalent of this on non-Debian systems. Google might help you.
Hope this can help a bit!

Edit: A little info for `yum`:
1. Search for package: `yum whatprovides <package_name>`
So for `pidof`  maybe:

```
yum whatprovides `which pidof`
```

2. Get the source: `yumdownloader --source <source_name>`. You may need `yum-utils` for this. More info at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-download-source-packages-from-rhn/)
Although I have not tried it, but I guess you can give a shot!

Comment: Thanks. I am on RH Enterprise Linux. I did rpm -qf /sbin/pidof which gave SysVinit-2.86-15.el5.x86_64. Then I downloaded SysVinit-2.86-15.el5.src.rpm, installed it and did tar -xvf sysvinit-2.86.tar.gz from /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES/. I see the pidof implementation in killall5.c

Comment: @Santhosh: Ah ok... I just googled some stuff & added in the edit! Well whatever works for you is good! You got that right, it is in `killall5.c`

Answer (score 2):

I found the pidof source code here: 
[Source Code](http://www.koders.com/c/fid80C38C715E43CB80C4E15CB469AE652F16FFB551.aspx?s=pidof#L3)

Comment: That's the BusyBox implementation, which relies on a library function `find_pid_by_name()` to do most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: How about [this](http://code.google.com/p/secured/source/browse/src/pidof.c?spec=svnd53f28f2475e9a969735475ae95d1e217e40a66e&r=d53f28f2475e9a969735475ae95d1e217e40a66e) .